# Getting started with creating a report with Crystal Reports 2008 for winform in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2000, c#-2.0, crystal-reports-2008

Can you please tell me how to integrate the CR 2008 into VS 2008 Team System as currently VS doen't give me the option to create Crystal reports using a template!!!
Please guide me...
The data on which the reports are to be based are in SQL Server 2000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Visual Studio Integration Manager](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/boc/crystalreports-dotnet?rid=/webcontent/uuid/80b94ac6-da77-2b10-dbbc-82b0c113d999)